# jQuery: slideDown doesnt work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

```
  function getRightCol(){
$('#right-col').slideDown(200).removeClass('hidden');
};
```

This function is called by clicking on a link - so that the right-col is shown. I tried to add some animation-classes before but i prefer using javascripts because older browsers doesnt support css3. So i decided to use jQuery to add some effect to make the user feel more comfortable. 
So, why does my #right-col doesnt slide down? What is wrong with my function? Do i need to do it with the `.on('click')`-function?

Comment: There is not enough code here to diagnose the problem. Can you put an example of the issue into a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: $('#right-col').slideDown('slow');

Comment: It'll be better if you'll post your code on jsFiddle because there is a lot of options.
Is your `right-col` dynamic element? It's created out of the page load and created after ajax complete? is the element visible?

Comment: @dholakiyaankit that is no different to what OP has now, other than trying to slide at a slower rate.

Comment: Ya i assume it but op doesnot have provided code i should ask for code(:)

Comment: Here is a very fast made fiddle js: http://jsfiddle.net/3NZFg/

Comment: I've updated your fiddle, you were not including jQuery.

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/3NZFg/11/, if you include jquery and put the javascript in the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't chain it that way, you have to remove the class as callback after the animation completes:

```
function getRightCol(){
    $('#right-col').slideDown(200, function () {
       $(this).removeClass('hidden');
    });
};
```

Comment: I'm guessing that hidden hides the right-col, in which case wouldn't you remove hidden **then** slideDown?

Comment: Seems to work fine as is with the right set up http://jsfiddle.net/3NZFg/11/

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(){
    $('#right-col').slideDown(200).removeClass('hidden');   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You better try it with [Jquery animate function](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp)

etc:

```
 $("div").animate({
    left:'250px',
    opacity:'0.5',
    height:'150px',
    width:'150px'
  });
```